# Impossible to use res.name because of subscribe (ANGULAR)

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

Currently I am following a tutorial on Youtube in which it uses authentication with Angular and I can't continue at this point :

[image: Code from Youtube tutorial]

His code does not work on my side because of subscribe() which gives me the message:

> @deprecated — Instead of passing separate callback arguments, use an
> observer argument. Signatures taking separate callback arguments will
> be removed in v8. Details:
> https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/subscribe-arguments

I'm forced to use `next`, `error` and `complete` and and despite everything, the `res.name` is not displayed.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.http.get(
    'http://localhost:8080/api/user',
    {withCredentials: true}
    ).subscribe({
    complete: () => { (res: any) => this.visiteur = `${res.nom}`  },
    error: () => { (err: any) => console.log(err)  },
    next: () => { (res: any) => this.visiteur = `${res.nom}`  }
    });
}
```

Comment: Questions here cannot depend on screenshots of text. Please transcribe the text into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current way of subscribing is using more of [rxjs operators](https://rxjs.dev/guide/operators), The tutorial you are following seems a little outdated. I recommend you follow angular's [Tour of heroes](https://angular.io/tutorial) tutorial instead. It is always up-to-date.

This should get you going:

```
this.http
    .get('http://localhost:8080/api/user')
    .pipe(
        catchError(err => {
            console.log(err);
        })
    )
    .subscribe(data => {
        this.visiteur = `${data.nom}`;
    });
```

Also I would recommend you implement an [angular http interceptor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) to pass in http required attributes/headers (in your case withCredentials). But this is optional for the scope of this question.

And finally, don't forget to avoid the [memory-leak](https://indepth.dev/posts/1433/rxjs-why-memory-leaks-occur-when-using-a-subject) trap with subscriptions.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer me, I appreciate it.
Thank you also for the links to the up-to-date tutorials, this will greatly help me.